# How to combine group plots in matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a large dataset with thousands of rows by country and year (longitudinal text data). As following dataframe shows `wordcount` column represents the number of occurrence of the word 'secular'.

```
df3
index    country      text                          wordcount  year
0        Bolivia      This is an example text..      1         2010
1        Bolivia      This is an example text2..     5         2015
2        Bolivia      This is an example text3 ..    7         2017
```

Now I would like to create sub-plots (scatter) for all countries separately where `year` will be on `x-axis` and `wordcount` on `y-axis` for each country. The following code gives me the desired plot for each country separately but I need to combine them. For instance, 10 countries will be in each row. Is there an easy way to do it? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. Please let me know if any clarifications are required.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for title, group in df3.groupby('country'):
    group.plot(x='year', y='wordcount', title=title)
```

**Update:**
I have also tried using the following code but I suppose it does not sum up the same value for `wordcount` multiple times in a year. In other words, I get fewer occurrences of words than in the previous codes (separate country plot).

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=11, ncols=8, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(18,10))
axes_list = [item for sublist in axes for item in sublist] 
for countryname, selection in df3.head(1200).groupby("country"):
    
    ax = axes_list.pop(0)
    selection.plot(x='year', y='wordcount', label=countryname, ax=ax, legend=False)
    ax.set_title(countryname)
    ax.tick_params(
        which='both',
        bottom='off',
        left='off',
        right='off',
        top='off'
    )
    ax.grid(linewidth=0.5)
    ax.set_xlim((1980, 2020))
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    ax.set_xticks(range(1980, 2020, 10))
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.set_ylim((0, 10))

for ax in axes_list:
    ax.remove()

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: try to construct a loop using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots

Comment: I tried this. I have just updated the code I used and the problem with it in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to count the total of `wordcount` values for each country for each year:

```
sum_df=pd.DataFrame(df3.groupby(['Country','year']).wordcount.sum()).reset_index()
```

Then:

```
df_pivot = sum_df.pivot(index='year', columns='Country', values='wordcount')
df_pivot.plot()
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error even after resetting year as index.

Comment: Perhaps there are cases where for the same `year` and `country` you have multiple `wordcount` values? You would need to deal with those first!

Comment: Yes, I have multiple `wordcount` values for the same `year` as each year has multiple rows/text files.

Comment: How would you like to deal with these multiple values? You want to take the mean, max, min or something else?

Comment: I would like to take the `count` or occurrence of them.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of `wordcount` values within the same year for each country?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The sum of `wordcount` for each year. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer to account for your comments. Please accept it if it solves your problem.

Comment: It still keeps showing `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. Not sure why though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217892/discussion-between-ali-hassaine-and-crackers).